# How do I change how a number is shown on a plot.ly graph?

Tags: plotly

I'm trying to make a scatter plot where one of the axis is money. Given a value like "11972.45", hovering over it shows it as "11.97245k".  While that is technically an accurate way to represent that value, I'd much rather see it as it was originally represented.

I didn't tag a programming language onto this because this doesn't appear to be language specific, I get the same result from just using their website directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `tickformat` option on the appropriate axis. If you're using `R`, the following example should help:

```
library(plotly)

# Dummy data
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3), 
                 y = c(114587, 125698, 221548))

# Uses the 'kilo' suffix by default
(p <- plot_ly(df, x = x, y = y, mode = 'markers'))

# No longer uses the 'kilo' suffix
p %>% layout(yaxis = list(tickformat = '0.0f'))
```